# Dimension of Subspace of Polynomial Space

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{F})$ to be the vector space of polynomials with degree less-than-or-equal to $n$, with either real or complex coefficients.

Is there a general way to find the dimension of a subspace such as $U:=\{p\in\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{F}):p(2)=p(4)\}$ or $W:=\{p\in\mathcal{P}_n(\mathbb{F}):p(1)=p(3)=p(5)\}$? Intuitively I'd guess $\dim U=n-1$ and $\dim W=n-2$, since they have one and two "constraints" respectively, but I don't know if this is true nor how to prove it.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: First off, the dimension of $\mathcal P_n(\mathbf F)$ is not $n$. Second, $\operatorname{codim} U=1,\operatorname{codim} W=2$ by the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: It is worth emphasizing that different authors use $\mathcal{P}_n$ in different ways.  Some authors use it to denote the set of degree less than or equal to $n$ polynomials, in which case the space is of dimension $n+1$ while other authors use it to denote the space of dimension $n$ which contains the set of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n-1$.  The difference being whether $n$ was in reference to the degrees or if $n$ was in reference to the dimension of the space.

Comment: As for understanding the problem you ask about, recall [Lagrange Interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial), that a polynomial of degree $n$ can be uniquely determined given $n+1$ points on the polynomial.  You can argue then that $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\cdots(x-n), x(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)\cdots(x-n),x(x-1)(x-3)(x-4)\cdots(x-n),\dots,x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1)$ form a basis for the space, the coefficient of these corresponding (*after an appropriate scaling factor for each*) to the value of $p(x)$ at the various values of $0,1,2,\dots,n$

Comment: @DonThousand Right, that was a mistake. Using the rank-nullity theorem makes it clear though, thank you!